# moonlandsoft/yii2-phpexcel - How to remove a blank sheet: WorkSheet?

Tags: yii2, phpspreadsheet

[image]How to remove a blank sheet: WorkSheet? My code

```
 \moonland\phpexcel\Excel::export([
        'isMultipleSheet' => true,
        'models' => [
            'sheet1' => Order::find()->all(),     
        ], 'columns' => [
            'sheet1' => ['id','phone','total'],   
        ],
        'headers' => [
            'sheet1' => ['column1' => 'id','column2' => 'phone', 'column3' => 'total']       
        ],
    ]);
```

Comment: hey can you mark the answer as correct if it worked for you?

Answer (score 0):

The extension you are using is widget that imports or exports data from php to excel or excel to php and it uses [`PHPSpreadsheet`](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet).

You can extend the widget to add your custom function and then call it to remove the worksheet.i will leave that part on to you to extend the widget and then use it.

For a basic example you can follow this

### Removing a Worksheet

You can delete a worksheet from a workbook, identified by its index position, using the `removeSheetByIndex()` method, and to get the index of any worksheet you need to use the `getIndex()` and `getSheetByName()` as you wont know the index but the name. See below.

```
$spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();
$sheetIndex = $spreadsheet->getIndex(
    $spreadsheet->getSheetByName('Worksheet 1')
);
$spreadsheet->removeSheetByIndex($sheetIndex);
```

If the currently active worksheet is deleted, then the sheet at the previous index position will become the currently active sheet.

Visit here for complete [Doc & Guide on Worksheets using PHPSpreadsheet](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/worksheets/)